# loop with variable in sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, loops, merge

I'm using SQLite Expert Personal 3 to access and write sql script for sqlite databases.
I have 30 sqlite databases that have same structure that i want to merge.
im using the following script.The main database has id as auto increment.

```
attach 'database0001.db3' as toimport;  
insert into [main].[Titles] select * from [toimport].[Titles];
insert into [main].[TitlesData] select * from [toimport].[TitlesData];
DETACH DATABASE toimport;
```

I can easily also create a database with the file names if its necessary.

Can this be done in a loop where a $variable is the name of file so i don't have to write same script 30 times?

Thank you and excuse the noob question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a scripting language can be used to write it 30 times so you don't have to.
Here's an example using perl, though many languages can do similar.

In each pass through the loop, the format specifier %04d causes the decimal value $variable to appear in a field of width four, left-padded with zeros.

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $formatString = "attach 'database%04d.db3' as toimport;
insert into [main].[Titles] select * from [toimport].[Titles];
insert into [main].[TitlesData] select * from [toimport].[TitlesData];
DETACH DATABASE toimport;\n";

for (my $variable = 1; $variable <= 30; ++$variable) {
        printf ($formatString, $variable);
}
```